# Is the ordinal $\omega \uparrow^\omega \omega$ still recursive?

Tags: computability, ordinals

In this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112101/cardinality-of-omega-uparrow-omega-omega), a very large countable ordinal $\omega \uparrow^\omega \omega$ is defined. Is this ordinal still recursive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. First, by induction, for each $n \in \omega$, $\omega \uparrow^n \omega$ is computable, uniformly in $n$. Second, $\omega \uparrow^\omega \omega$ is just the limit, which is to say the sum, of these.